# Fetch calculated advanced price for a product for each customer group via API

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am currently trying to get the calculated price (advanced pricing) for each customer group via the [API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/8faf525d8ec07-fetch-a-single-product).
I started with checking out the [context](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/489d07a667582-fetch-the-current-context) and also found an endpoint for [modifying the context](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/abad38ec1647b-modify-the-current-context). But you can't modify the customer group there.
Is there a way to calculate the advanced pricing for each customer group via the API?

Inside a plugin, I was using `Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Price\ProductPriceCalculator`, but I can't use that in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different API's that you could work with. You could consider the Admin API as well for this job.

The one you are referencing is the Storefront API. Which means you are querying (browsing) as if you were a customer or a guest. So when you are querying a single product, it is as if you are going to the desktop site as a guest, and asking the price of the product. Guests do have a default customer group assigned to them too. Therefore, the `calculatedPrice` & `calculatedPrices[]` will reflect all the prices that are available to this guest.

If you want to see the product as a specific customer (who could have a different Customer Group assigned to them), you will need to log in:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost/store-api/account/login \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'sw-access-key: SW_ACCESS_KEY' \
  --data '{
  "username": "test@example.com",
  "password": "shopware"
}'
```

In the response you get a context token with which you can query the product as a customer:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/store-api/product/11dc680240b04f469ccba354cbf0b967' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'sw-context-token: CONTEXT_TOKEN' \
--header 'sw-access-key: SW_ACCESS_KEY'
```

If you had configured the product prices for a specific customerGroup & assigned the customer that group, you will now see a different `calculatedPrice` than of just of a guest.

---

For the Admin API it will be a bit more detailed, and will not be nicely calculated for you. Assume you have a specific "RULE" that allows customer from group X to have the price of the product. You get the ruleId, get the productId & query the Admin API:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/api/search/product-price' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer BEARER_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "multi",
            "operator": "and",
            "queries": [
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "productId",
                    "value": "11dc680240b04f469ccba354cbf0b967"
                },
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "ruleId",
                    "value": "9af98c92c57a4cc0a0b1364454266c1c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Ok, so Option 1 will not work, because I don't have the credentials for any customer.

Regarding Option 2:
So I would still need to implement a way, to fetch all applying rules, as there can also be other conditions like sales channel, language and currency. And those can also be stacked within OR/AND containers.

Comment: Yup, as far as I know, that's the whole thing about the Admin API, it has no context, it gives you data in the rawest form. Storefront digests the raw data for the customer using context. Another way would be to create a plugin that extends an endpoint & accepts a group id.

Comment: I need it for my SW App, so a plugin will not be a solution, as they do not work within the Shopware Cloud.